# transaction not available?

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, informix

Q:

When i call the following method:

```
con.Begin_Transaction();
```

Method implementation:

```
 public void Begin_Transaction()
        {
            if (this.connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                this.current_trans = this.connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
            }
        }
```

Use the following Classes:

```
         DbProviderFactory providerFactory;
         IfxConnection connection;
         IfxCommand command;
         IfxTransaction m_current_trans;
         IfxParameter param;
         IfxDataReader DR;
```

---

**I get the following exception:**

> IBM.Data.Informix.If Exception: ERROR
>   [HY000] [Informix .NET
>   provider][Informix]Transaction not
>   available

What is the problem here please?
thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try with another kind of transaction ?

Comment: Is logging turned on for the database ?

Comment: Excuse me , what do you mean by another kind of transaction?

Comment: yeah , i connected normally to the database.and the connection state is `open`

Comment: @just_name try to change the InsolationLevel

Comment: @Felice Pollano:change it to what?

Comment: @just_name for example InsolationLevel.ReadCommitted

Comment: `Chaos`,`ReadCommitted`,`ReadUnCommitted`,`RepeatableRead`,`Serializable`,`SnapShot`,`Unspecified`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Transactions to work the database should be **logging** enabled, Please check if its done for your case, used in cases since it would be needed to undo changes

Comment: what do you mean by logging , and how to make sure

Comment: Check [this out](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst163.htm)

Comment: this is a great.`Dynamic Server allows you to turn on logging with the WITH LOG clause in the CREATE DATABASE statement.`
I have already created my data base how to allow logging.

Comment: `ontape -s [-A database_list] [-B database_list] `

Comment: I think `ontape` is a utility .. May be you could try as [This](http://www.dbforums.com/informix/975365-how-determine-if-logical-log-mode-enabled.html)

Comment: thanks u so much, this fixes my problem. is it a must to clarify the`logging` during creating the database in just `informix` or in other DBMSes. because i never face this in `sql server` for example.

Comment: The default setting for  SQL Server (sure of 2005) is set to Full Recovery Mode, so no need to specify in such cases